# Import data from Excel into a service-based database

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, datatable

So i'm trying to get information from an excel spreadsheet into a service-based database for use in a Windows Form Application. Is there a way to import the information vs having to hand key all the information into the service based database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that the data in the excel spreadsheet is somewhat 1:1 with the database schema.

It seems like when you say service-based you have only end point to use but in case that's not correct going to ask anyway, do you have database access?

If yes, use excel and batch create your insert statements on each row of the excel sheet:

"="Insert into tablename values('" & A1 & "','"& B1 & "','" & C1 & "','" & D1 & "','" & E1 & "')"
Once you have this formula in Cell F1, copy it to Cells F2:F50000 and the formula will automatically adjust to create the right insert statements for you."

then just execute them on sql server.

http://www.excel-formulas.com/sample-question/Create-SQL-Query-From-Columns

You could also use SSIS to import from excel if you have that as an option, again with access to the database. Too many steps to list here but: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server---10-steps-to-follow/ is a good guide regarding that.

If you don't have access to the database and you can't send the file to a dba that runs the database then I it would appear that the only option is to repeatedly call a call on the service that you have exposed for entry of the data. In that case you may want to save it as CSV and make a console application that parses the CSV to import your data.

If I could comment I'd ask you some more specifics/constraints about your setup.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My setup is that I'm creating a windows form that will be used at my local job that needs a service based dB for landing zones.